# Chart not rendering on page navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, charts, c3.js

I have a list page (**List.Html**) where n number of rows can be selected, in order to visually display the row data in a chart (using [C3](http://c3js.org/)).

This is done by clicking on a button (**compareList()**) that navigates to a new page (**Chart.Html**). The problem is that the chart is not displaying on the new page, possibly because the chart data is being loaded before the page is loading meaning the HTML where the chart needs to be inserted is not found.

If the Chart Page is loaded before the list page, the chart is generated but 
only once upon click but then is lost.

**Controller.js**

```
$scope.compareList = function(){
    var total = $scope.array.length;
    var tempArray= [];
    for(var i=0; i<total; i++){
      if($scope.array[i].selected){
        tempArray[i] = $scope.array[i];
      }
    }
    if(comparr.length>0){
      $scope.compGraph(tempArray);
    }
  }


$scope.compGraph = function(array){
var tempData = [];
for(var i=0; i<array.length;i++){
  tempData.push([array[i].name,array[i].evi]);
}

var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
      columns: tempData,
      type:'bar'
    }
});

$state.go('eventmenu.compare');

}
```

**List.Html**

```
<ion-view view-title="List">
        <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
            <button class="button button-icon icon ion-stats-bars" ng-click="compareList()"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
        <ion-content>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" class="item-remove-animate">
                <div class="row" >
                    <div class="col col-40"{{ item.name }}</div>
                    <div class="col col-30" style=";">{{ item.area}}m<sup>2</sup></div> 
                    <div class="col col-20" style=";">{{ item.value}}</div>
                    <div class="col col-10  col-top" ><ion-checkbox style="border:none;margin-top: -20px;" ng-model="item.selected"></ion-checkbox></div>
                </div>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>   
    </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

**Chart.HTML**

```
<ion-view view-title="Land Comparison">
  <ion-content ng-controller="Controller">
        <div class="padding">
                <div id="chart" ></div>
        </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using `ng-if` for charts. Set a value for listen to loading situation and use it.

In HTML:

```
<div class="padding">
    <div ng-if="isDataLoaded" id="chart"></div>
</div>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.isDataLoaded = false;

function loadData(){
    $scope.myData = [1,2,3];
    $scope.isDataLoaded = true;
}
```

Comment: The problem is still occurring. It seems to always be false.

Comment: Control isDataLoaded @neilfar

Comment: I am setting true by default and hard-coding chart data to verify that the chart will show when true but it is still hidden.

Comment: Could you try ng-if="isDataLoaded === true" ? @neilfar

Comment: It seems to be an issue from the charts. The ng-if works perfectly on other div elements.